# Pusher with PHP And Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I want to implement pusher with php and javascript.

I have included pusher library for php with composer.

And my php code is

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$app_id = "XX";
$app_key = "XX";
$app_secret = "XX";
$cluster = "ap1";

$pusher = new Pusher( $app_key, $app_secret, $app_id, array( 'encrypted' => true ) );

$pusher->trigger( 'XX-channel', 'test', 'hello world' );
```

And in javascript

```
<head>
    <title>Pusher</title>
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        const socket = new Pusher("XXX", {
            cluster: 'ap1'
        });
        const channel = socket.subscribe('XX-channel');

        channel.bind('test', function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

But when I refresh page I dont receive any console logs.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the JS before the PHP triggers ?

Comment: Also.. Are you not supposed to be setting up a websocket server (possibly nodeJS??) to listen to messages ? Are you seeing anything there ?

Comment: I just tried refreshing php page to receive log.

Comment: You should be able to identify whether the cause of the issue is your PHP or javascript code using the debug console in your pusher app dashboard. If you're able to see your `console.logs` when you send `test` events to `XX-Channel` using the event creator, the issue is in your PHP code and you should [enable logging](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#debugging--logging) to try and help track this down.

Comment: @leesio Thanks. Issue is with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pusher = new Pusher( $app_key, $app_secret, $app_id, array( 'cluster'=> $cluster) );

$pusher->trigger( 'XX-channel', 'test', 'hello world' );
```

Found issue.

I forgot to add cluster.